# Passing data to SOAP Function with PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

[SOAP Resource - Test](http://www.quadranet.co.uk/qsldemowebservice/)

Hey,
I am trying to send some XML through to this Soap Web service but not having any luck, I am hitting the Test() function because I can see the output coming back, but the info I pass through to that function should be returned inside, please refer to the link above.

The code I am using is below - any guidance would be appreciated.

```
try {

        $soap_headers = new \SoapHeader(
            'POST /qslwebservice/QSLWebBooking.asmx HTTP/1.1',
            'Host: qslwebsrv',
            'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
            'SOAPAction: "http://www.resv5.com/webservices/Test"'
        );

        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.resv5.com/webservices"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><web:Test><web:xmldata>mike test</web:xmldata></web:Test></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';

        $_test_xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
        $test_xml = $_test_xml->asXML();


        $url = esc_url('http://www.quadranet.co.uk/qsldemowebservice/QSLWebBooking.asmx?wsdl');

        $client = new \SoapClient($url); //create new Soap instance

        $types = $client->__getTypes(); //list types found at resource
        $functions = $client->__getFunctions(); //list functions found at resource

        $test = $client->Test($test_xml); //call Test() at resource


        echo '<br><hr>';
        var_dump($test);

    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        print_r($e);
    }
```

Comment: > I can see the output coming back, but the info I pass through to that function should be returned inside

please elaborate this.

Comment: You are doing way too much in your code. `$soap_headers` are useless because that are HTTP headers - Soap headers are something different, they go into the "headers" section of the SOAP XML data if necessary (usually not). Then you are creating all the XML that is the request. This is done by the Soap client itself when calling any of the Soap actions of the remote service. Additionally, you usually do not need to call `__getTypes()` or `__getFunctions()` if you already know the capabilities of the service. And what is that `esc_url()` function doing?

Comment: morning guys, thanks for your comments, if I can answer both. @philip : If I pass through a string to that Test() function I expect that string to be returned along with the output of the Test() function.

@sven: esc_url() checks and cleans a URL. With regards to the $soap_headers, I was unaware of that - I can remove them. As for the __getFunctions & __getTypes These functions are not actually being used by me, I left them in incase anyone wanted to run the code and output what is returned.

If I understand @sven correctly, are you saying that I could simply run `$client->Test('hello');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to say thanks to @sven + @mikael , took me a while to figure it out but your comments about what is generated by the soap client helped me to figure out the answer. if you look at the $xml variable in my question and compare it to the below

`$xml = '<Test xmlns="http://www.resv5.com/webservices"><xmldata>TESTING</xmldata></Test>';`

you'll notice that I didnt need to pass through as much xml data as I thought, once I knew exactly what had to be passed through it was simple.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitively use a WSDL to php generator so you won't wonder how to send the request and you'll wuickly see if you have any error in your request.

In my optinion you're misunderstanding what you have to send as the envlopped is auto-generated by the SoapClient class. The Test method is waiting for a single simplier string parameter.

Try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project.